# Ordinals as Trees

Tags: ordinals, trees

I'm trying to understand countable ordinals and their tree representation.

I understand that $\omega$ is the first "non branching tree" of infinite height.

I also understand that the exponent of $\omega$, so $\omega^2$ for example, corresponds to the node of the tree. So here we would have a tree of height $2$, for $\omega^3$ a tree of height $3$ etc.

So would the following two constructions be correct for $\omega \cdot 3$ (left) and $\omega^2$ (right):

[image: omega]

Comment: Which tree representation are you looking at?  There are several different ones, and usually when people talk about tree representations for countable ordinals they're talking about _finite_ trees, so I'm not sure why you're talking about a tree of infinite height for $\omega$.

Comment: Given omega is a limit, how else would you represent  as a finite tree?

Comment: The typical tree representation doesn't 'respect' limits; if $T_n$ are the trees representing ordinals $o_n$ and $\mathcal{o}=\lim o_n$ is the limit of the ordinals, then its tree $\mathcal{T}$ isn't necessarily the limit of the $T_n$.

Comment: ok. So considering finite trees, is the diagram drawn above correct?

Comment: The above diagram isn't a finite tree.  You still haven't explained _which_ tree representation you're talking about; that phrase has a few different meanings, and without knowing more about the background and what specifically you're trying to understand (I've been _assuming_ that you're interested in the way of representing ordinals less than $\epsilon_0$ as finite trees, and vice versa, but I could be wrong) it's hard to offer more specific help.

Comment: I'm looking at ordinal trees. The above has "..." on the right because I wanted to illustrate what the pattern should be for any value. 

The above is the only representation I know of trees for omega (really bad teacher...), so I"m just trying to make sense of the whole thing.

Comment: What is "the node of the tree" as referring to the exponent of $\omega$? (I'm not sure if it's height, since the tree for $\omega$ has infinite height while $\omega=\omega^1$.)